# WSDL file not generating while creating SOAP web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I have created a SOAP webservice through eclipse, but wsdl file is not being generated, although I am able to see the services listing when I run the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Axis 2 for creating SOAP web service, because of that my WSDL was not generating since as soon as I changed the Web service engine from Axis 2 to Axis , wsdl got generated.